# Merging dataframes based on multiple types of conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have two dataframes, df1 and df2. In one dataframe, the data is gathered from every individual ID. However, some IDs work together and in the second dataframe the coupled IDs are shown. The dataframes look like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Polar', 'Dex', 'Nikita', 'Lunar', 'Astro', 'Pin', 'Polar'], 'Date': ['01-03-2023', '01-03-2023', '02-03-2023', '03-03-2023', '04-03-2023', '04-03-2023', '05-03-2023'], 'Hours': ['5', '8', '9', '11', '12', '2', '6']})
df2 = pd.Dataframe({'Couple': ['Polar-Dex', 'Astro-Pin'], 'Date': ['01-03-2023', '04-03-2023']})
```

As you can see, Polar & Dex and Astro & Pin worked together on some dates. Now, I want to capture these couples and add them into a new column in df1 based on both their date and that the Couple of df2 contains the ID of df1. And if there is nothing to match using these conditions, I want it to return just the ID.

The new dataframe should look like this:

| ID | Date | Hours | Couple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Polar | 01-03-2023 | 5 | Polar-Dex |
| Dex | 01-03-2023 | 8 | Polar-Dex |
| Nikita | 02-03-2023 | 9 | Nikita |
| Lunar | 03-03-2023 | 11 | Lunar |
| Astro | 04-03-2023 | 12 | Astro-Pin |
| Pin | 04-03-2023 | 2 | Astro-Pin |
| Polar | 05-03-2023 | 6 | Polar |

I have tried iterating, I have tried using np.where, but nothing seemed to work. Anybody who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Polar', 'Dex', 'Nikita', 'Lunar', 'Astro', 'Pin', 'Polar'], 'Date': ['01-03-2023', '01-03-2023', '02-03-2023', '03-03-2023', '04-03-2023', '04-03-2023', '05-03-2023'], 'Hours': ['5', '8', '9', '11', '12', '2', '6']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Couple': ['Polar-Dex', 'Astro-Pin'], 'Date': ['01-03-2023', '04-03-2023']})
temp = []
for i in range(len(df1.Date)):
  flag = True 
  for j in range(len(df2.Date)):
    if df1.Date[i] in list(df2.Date) and df1.ID[i] in df2.Couple[j].split("-"):
      temp.append(df2.Couple[j])
      flag = False;
      break;
  if flag:
    temp.append(df1.ID[i])

df1['Couple'] = temp
print(df1)
```

output:

```
      ID        Date Hours     Couple
0   Polar  01-03-2023     5  Polar-Dex
1     Dex  01-03-2023     8  Polar-Dex
2  Nikita  02-03-2023     9     Nikita
3   Lunar  03-03-2023    11      Lunar
4   Astro  04-03-2023    12  Astro-Pin
5     Pin  04-03-2023     2  Astro-Pin
6   Polar  05-03-2023     6      Polar
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that, the given df is only an example. There are many more different IDs on for example the first of March. This solution only appends based on Date.

Comment: We are really close to the answer. The only thing is that there may be other couples on the same date as well, so now it gives an error regarding the .item() part of the function because the list returns more than one couple value.

Comment: Edited again. Try it and tell me if there is some mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Polar', 'Dex', 'Nikita', 'Lunar', 'Astro', 'Pin', 'Polar'], 'Date': ['01-03-2023', '01-03-2023', '02-03-2023', '03-03-2023', '04-03-2023', '04-03-2023', '05-03-2023'], 'Hours': ['5', '8', '9', '11', '12', '2', '6']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Couple': ['Polar-Dex', 'Astro-Pin'], 'Date': ['01-03-2023', '04-03-2023']})

df2[['ID1', 'ID2']] = df2['Couple'].str.split('-', expand=True)

merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Date', how='left')
merged_df.loc[merged_df['ID'].isin(df2['ID1']) & merged_df['ID'].isin(df2['ID2']), 'Couple'] = merged_df['ID1'] + '-' + merged_df['ID2']
merged_df['Couple'] = merged_df['Couple'].fillna(merged_df['ID'])

merged_df = merged_df.drop(['ID1', 'ID2'], axis=1)

print(merged_df)
```

which gives you

```
       ID        Date Hours     Couple
0   Polar  01-03-2023     5  Polar-Dex
1     Dex  01-03-2023     8  Polar-Dex
2  Nikita  02-03-2023     9     Nikita
3   Lunar  03-03-2023    11      Lunar
4   Astro  04-03-2023    12  Astro-Pin
5     Pin  04-03-2023     2  Astro-Pin
6   Polar  05-03-2023     6      Polar
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the given dfs are only examples. There are way more IDs on for example the first of March and there are many more couples on the first of March. By only merging on Date, these get mixed up and the right couple isnt matched with the right ID.